# Collection View cells to fit exactly 3 per row in all devices swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, frame, collectionview

I am trying to make a collection view of images, so that there are 3 per row, with some spacing in between.

Code:-

```
func setupCollectioView(){
    guard let collectionView = gridPhotosCollectionview, let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 2
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2, right: 2)
    gridPhotosCollectionview.delegate = self
    gridPhotosCollectionview.dataSource = self
}


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
  return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return images.count 
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let noOfCellsInRow = 3
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))
    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let totalCount = selectedImages.count + selectedPostDetailImages.count
    if totalCount == 1 {
        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: collectionView.frame.width - flowLayout.itemSize.width)
    }
    return UIEdgeInsets.zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
```

The above code works on all the devices from iPhone 11. it's not working below the iPhone 11. Please check the attached screenshots.

**iPhone 11 Screen Shot**:-

[image: Screen Shot]

**iPhone XS Screen Shot**:-

[image: Screen Shot]

Question: How to set the cells frame to fit exactly 3 per row in all devices, Swift?

Can someone please explain to me how to do this, I've tried with the above code but have no results yet. Please Correct me if I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check gridPhotosCollectionview and set min and max space to 0

Comment: Could you print `collectionView.width` when setting the size, and the screen width? I'm wondering if that's the issue, that when the collectionView is firstly created and rendered, the didLayoutSubview hasn't been done totally. (in both "devices")

Comment: I fixed it already. it's my mistake I didn't set the estimated size to none. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It's my mistake I didn't set the estimated size to none. It's working fine now.

[image: ScreenShot]